Whatsapp Webhook API not working on cPanel
(https://i.sstatic.net/gVF6HTIz.png) (https://i.sstatic.net/GPabyiiQ.png)
I am trying to integrate the Whatsapp API Webhook on a Node.JS server on cPanel. I have copied the code from the docs and it works perfectly on Glitch. The server starts fine but when I try to add the webhook on the facebook app page, there is no request received on the Node.JS server. These are the packages I have in package.json:


"@google-cloud/local-auth": "^2.1.0",



"axios": "^1.7.2",



"dotenv": "^16.4.5",



"express": "^4.19.2",



"google-auth-library": "^9.10.0",



"googleapis": "^105.0.0",



"googleapis-common": "^7.2.0"



This is the code for my server.js:
import express from "express";
import axios from "axios";
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

console.log("WEBHOOK_VERIFY_TOKEN:", process.env.WEBHOOK_VERIFY_TOKEN);
console.log("GRAPH_API_TOKEN:", process.env.GRAPH_API_TOKEN);
console.log("PORT:", process.env.PORT);

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const { WEBHOOK_VERIFY_TOKEN, GRAPH_API_TOKEN, PORT = 3000 } = process.env;

app.post("/webhook", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("Incoming webhook message:", JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2));

  const message = req.body.entry?.[0]?.changes[0]?.value?.messages?.[0];

  if (message?.type === "text") {
    const business_phone_number_id =
      req.body.entry?.[0].changes?.[0].value?.metadata?.phone_number_id;

    try {
      await axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: `https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/${business_phone_number_id}/messages`,
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${GRAPH_API_TOKEN}`,
        },
        data: {
          messaging_product: "whatsapp",
          to: message.from,
          text: { body: "Echo: " + message.text.body },
          context: { message_id: message.id },
        },
      });

      await axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: `https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/${business_phone_number_id}/messages`,
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${GRAPH_API_TOKEN}`,
        },
        data: {
          messaging_product: "whatsapp",
          status: "read",
          message_id: message.id,
        },
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error sending reply:", error);
    }
  }

  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.get("/webhook", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Webhook verification request:", req.query);
  const mode = req.query["hub.mode"];
  const token = req.query["hub.verify_token"];
  const challenge = req.query["hub.challenge"];

  if (mode === "subscribe" && token === process.env.WEBHOOK_VERIFY_TOKEN) {
    res.status(200).send(challenge);
    console.log("Webhook verified successfully!");
  } else {
    console.log("Webhook verification failed. Mode:", mode, "Token:", token);
    res.sendStatus(403);
  }
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send(`<pre>Nothing to see here. Checkout README.md to start.</pre>`);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port: ${PORT}`);
});

